# Buying a new and different buggy chassis

Tags: purchasing

I successfully made the buggy from the raspberry pi website: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy
and I am happy with it because it works and everything.

BUT the chassis is made out of... well it looks like particle board, probably with asbestos, whatever material it is I do not to like it.

Does anyone know of a set (like erector sets but not that exact set) that I can build a chassis out of that is made out of a better material?

Comment: your question has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi .... why are you asking it here?

Comment: It won't contain asbestos if made in the UK. Asbestos is completely banned here.

Comment: Well, the Rpi buggy project tutorial says the following: "... but in this project, a cardboard box is used as a temporary solution, ...". The cardboard box looks ugly and damages the reputation of projects.raspberrypi.org.  Perhaps you can google a deluxe model to replace the ugly thing.

Comment: @jsotola it is the pi buggy which is a pi project, but you are right, this question would be better on the pi forums.  Oops, my asking in the wrong place was unintentional.

Comment: @dougie the chassis was made in China... but that is good to know that it is banned in the uk

Comment: @tlfong01 yeah I googled deluxe pi buggy and found this: https://www.google.com/shopping/product/1?lsf=seller:16705561,store:16774769696904428477&prds=pid:9436221797738061389,oid:5947123553296426556&q=raspberry+pi+deluxe+chassis&hl=en&ei=QqMFXafRB6Hr5gL9qJeQCw&lsft=gclid:EAIaIQobChMI8p2Gs_Ts4gIVD7bICh27NgvnEAQYBCABEgJrzvD_BwE which I'll buy, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @thecanmanisback2, but I forgot to check out if you have already read the GpioZero soruce code a couple of times, and have already successfully moved your 4WD (yes, not 2WD) a perfect square.  Otherwise your buggy only deserves an ordinary cheapy plastic chassis, not a proud Erector class metallic titanium bullet proof model -  https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/robot-chassis-kit.html

Comment: BTW, my dream car, BlueTooth, but Arduino only :( - Keyestudio DIY Mini Tank Smart Robot Car Kit for Arduino Robot Education Programming + Manual + 5 Projects -

https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/2016-NEW-Keyestudio-Mini-Tank-Robot-for-arduino-Robot-car-Smart-car/32660935029.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.66.94e753fey1I2Hw&s=p&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10084_10083_10887_10307_321_453_322_454_10618_536_10065_317_537_10068_319_10059_10103_10884_10696,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=59c17874-bb67-4950-ab4a-e8af5032f87f&algo_expid=59c17874-bb67-4950-ab4a-e8af5032f87f-7

Comment: @thecanmanisback2, your might like to look at my 4WD chassis! :) (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99460/motor-wont-stop/99465#99465
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=234304#p1440566

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> Does anyone know of a set (like erector sets but not that exact set)
>   that I can build a chassis out of that is made out of a better
>   material?

***Answer***

> I have a suggestion.

[image: 4wd chassis]

[tlfong01's L298B Motor Driver Testing Notes](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99460/motor-wont-stop/99465#99465)

[tlfong01's 4WD Plastic Box Cover Chassis](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=234304#p1440566)