# RaspberryPi is not provided with enough power

Tags: power-supply, battery, voltage

Im trying to learn robotics with raspberrypi but im having a problem.
I have 6 AA batteries that are connected to a LM2596S adjustable voltage regulator module, Which then is connected to the raspberryPi.
I turned down the V provided to about 5V, but as fast as I provide power to the Pi it drops down to about 4V which is not enough power for the pi to run and makes it shut down. I have tried adjusting the power (out) to 6,7V but the same thing keeps happening when I connect it to the Pi, the V (out) drops down to 4V.
The V (IN to the module) shows about 8.2V when not connected to the pi, but drops down aswell as soon as I connect it.
What hardware is most likely damaged here and what should I try?

The Pi runs perfectly fine when connected to a power adapter.

Comment: You need a constant-voltage converter. Sounds like that’s not what you have.

Comment: The voltage doesn't matter if you cannot supply enough current. Either your LM2596 cannot source enough current or your batteries cannot put out enough.

Comment: The Pi seems to be irrelevant to this question.

Comment: This rpi.org.projects tutoriual might help: "How to [DIY] your own [Lipo 18650] power bank": https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy/4, WARNING: connecting 6/7V DC PSU to Rpi overloads its regulator, over heating Rpi, and would shortens its life.  One get around is use 2 LM2596 PSUs, one for Rpi, the other for motor.  The thread might also help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100992/powerbank-for-raspberry-pi-3-b-car-robot